# AWS region in AWS Glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

How can I get the region in which the current Glue job is executing?

---

When the Glue job starts executing, I see the output

> `Detected region eu-central-1`.

In AWS Lambda, I can use the following lines to fetch the current region:

```
import os
region = os.environ['AWS_REGION']
```

However, it seems like the `AWS_REGION` environment variable is not present in Glue and therefore a `KeyError` is raised:

> `KeyError: 'AWS_REGION'`

---

The reason why I need the region is I am trying to fetch all databases and tables as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46095508/303598) and I do not want to hard code the region when creating the boto client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to pass the `AWS_REGION` as a job parameter. For example, if you trigger the job from Lambda:

```
import os

response = client.start_job_run(
    JobName = 'a_job_name',
    Arguments = {'--AWS_REGION': os.environ['AWS_REGION'] } 
)
```

Alternatively, if you define your jobs using the [AWS::Glue::Job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-job.html) CloudFormation resource:

```
GlueJob:
  Type: AWS::Glue::Job
  Properties:
    Role: !Ref GlueRole
    DefaultArguments:
      "--AWS_REGION": !Sub "${AWS::Region}"
    Command:
      ScriptLocation: !Sub s3://${GlueScriptBucket}/glue-job.py
      Name: glueetl
```

Then you can extract the `AWS_REGION` parameter in your job code using [getResolvedOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-get-resolved-options.html):

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['AWS_REGION'])
print('region', args['AWS_REGION'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']` instead.
Leaving this here for new visitors.

Comment: Nope. I'm getting a `KeyError: 'AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'`. Any other suggestions?

Comment: when I tried printing `os.environ` I got this response from the glue job, 
`environ({
    "PATH": "<VALUE>",
    "HOSTNAME": "<VALUE>",
    "USE_PROXY": "<VALUE>",
    "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION": "us-east-1",
    "GLUE_PYTHON_VERSION": "3",
    "ERROR_FILE_NAME_LOCATION": "<VALUE>",
    "LANG": "<VALUE>",
    "GPG_KEY": "<VALUE>",
    "PYTHON_VERSION": "<VALUE>",
    "PYTHON_PIP_VERSION": "<VALUE>",
    "PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL": "<VALUE>",
    "PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256": "<VALUE>",
    "PYTHONPATH": ":<VALUE>",
    "GLUE_INSTALLATION": "<VALUE>",
    "HOME": "/"
})`

Comment: I am using **Python shell** as the glue job type, if you are using "Spark" or "Spark Streaming" I suggest just run a small script as simple as `import os print(os.environ)` that should give you a list of all environment vars

Comment: Ok. Being new to Glue/Spark, I didn't realize the difference. Indeed, I'm running a Spark job, not Python job.

Comment: This solution seems to work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719318/1548275

Answer (score 0):

`os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']` works for Glue versions **2.0 and 3.0**, but does not exist in previous versions. It gives the region code, for example `us-east-1`.

This was confirmed through running a small PySpark script to print out the environment variables, on all the Glue versions, as suggested by the other answer.