# How to pass AWS Region to lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, terraform

I currently have a lambda that reads from my DynamoDB and S3, where I pass in us-east-1 as the region. I am now deploying a backup region as well, but I am not sure how to make the region variable in my lambda based on whether it's in the default region or warm/backup region. Is there a way to detect what region my lambda is running on, whether in Terraform where I have my lambda set up or anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, Lambda functions have access to various [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html), including:

- AWS_REGION
- AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME
- AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME
- AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried looking up the same for Glue and my UI (S3, Route53, Cloudfront) but couldn't find environment variables besides default region. When I tried using the same way of retrieving the region variable on Glue as the Lambda docs, it didn't work. Any recs?

Comment: Ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52149901/271415) for Glue ETL scripts. Not sure what you're referring to when you say UI.